# how to get total count of 2nd/3rd inner list of object using Linq or lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a class structure like this

```
class ABC
{
    public List<A> LA { get; set; }
}
class A
{
    public List<B> LB { get; set; }
}

class B 
{
    public List<C> LC { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }
}
```

Here, as you can see that class "abc" can have multiple objects/elements of class "A" and each element of class "A" can have multiple elements of class "B" and each element of class "B" can have multiple elements of class "C". Now I want to calculate total No of elements of class "C" and store that total count in a int type variable by using Linq or lambda expression and without foreach loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an example data?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you posted an answer and then deleted it... that was perfect..

Answer (score 4):

You could sum them on each list.

`abc.LA.Sum(xabc => xabc.LB.Sum(xb => xb.LC.Count))`

Here is an example how you could do it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class ABC
    {
        public List<A> LA { get; set; }
    }

    class A
    {
        public List<B> LB { get; set; }
    }

    class B
    {
        public List<C> LC { get; set; }
    }

    class C
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {

        var abc = new ABC 
        { 
            LA = new List<A> 
            { 
                new A 
                { 
                    LB = new List<B> 
                    { 
                        new B 
                        { 
                            LC = new List<C> 
                            { 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3}, 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3} 
                            } 
                        },
                        new B 
                        { 
                            LC = new List<C> 
                            { 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3}, 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3} 
                            } 
                        } 

                    } 
                },
                new A 
                { 
                    LB = new List<B> 
                    { 
                        new B 
                        { 
                            LC = new List<C> 
                            { 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3}, 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3} 
                            } 
                        },
                        new B 
                        { 
                            LC = new List<C> 
                            { 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3}, 
                                new C { x =1, y= 2, z= 3} 
                            } 
                        } 

                    } 
                } 

            } 
        };

        Console.WriteLine(abc.LA.Sum(xabc => xabc.LB.Sum(xb => xb.LC.Count)));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

abc.LA.SelectMany(la => la.LB).SelectMany(lb => lb.LC).Count();